# Export an entended/custom styled component interface

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am unable to (figure out how to) export an interface that includes the built-in Styled Components props (i.e. `as`) alongside my additional custom properties.

### Context

I have made a styled component called `CustomTypography` that provides the opportunity to add typographic styling constrained to predefined configurations, while still being able to choose what HTML element to insert by passing the `as` polymorphic SC property.

*Note: I have attempted to simplify the code in order not to add distraction and unnecessary complexity. In doing so, I might have written a silly component, but please bear with me.*

**Interface (simplified):**

```
interface CustomTypographyProps {
  $typography?: 'display' | 'legible';
  $size?: 'mega' | 'mini';
}
```

**Component, (simplified):**

```
export const CustomTypography = styled.div<CustomTypographyProps>`
  font-family: ${({ $typography = 'legible' }) => {
    return $typography === 'display' ? 'Arial, sans-serif' : 'Georgia, serif';
  }};
  font-size: ${({ $size = 'mini' }) => {
    return $size === 'mega' ? '2rem' : '1rem';
  }};
`;
```

When I use the component itself works fine, but the problem arises when I extend the component to create a preconfigured typography and then attempt to access/pass the `as` property in the *preconfigured/precomposed* component.

**Precomposed component (simplified):**

```
const LegibleTypography = styled(CustomTypography).attrs((props) => {
  return {
    $typography: 'legible'
    $size: props.as === 'h1' ? 'mega' : undefined;
    //           ^ Error here
  }
})``;
```

Since the `CustomTypographyProps` interface only contains my additional props, typescript complains when I attempt to access the `as` property and I get the following error.

```
Property 'as' does not exist on type 'Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> & { ...; } & ThemeProps<...>'
.ts(2339)
```

I suspect that the solution might be fairly straight-forward, but as I am still somewhat new to typescript, inspecting the SC types source code without actual documentation  or examples is no trivial task for me (and I have now spent a considerable amount of time doing so).

Answer (score 0):

So, one solution could be if I manually add the `as` property by mirroring the implementation in [@types/styled-components](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/styled-components/index.d.ts) it should work, but I would much rather use the actual interface/type to avoid duplicating code and issues that would arise in case it were to change.

```
import styled, { IntrinsicElementsKeys } from 'styled-components';

// ...

interface CustomTypographyProps {
  $typography?: 'display' | 'legible';
  $size?: 'mega' | 'mini';
  as: IntrinsicElementsKeys;
}
```

I'm almost certain there is a way to do this properly, I simply cannot decipher how to do it.